# Solving $c \sqrt{1+y'^2} - \rho g y + \lambda = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following DE which corresponds to the hanging chain problem. Just need help to get started. Kinda stuck at that point. $\rho$, $\lambda$ and $g$ are all real. Thanks.

$c \sqrt{1+y'^2} - \rho g y + \lambda = 0$

Comment: I think that it's difficult to solve it exactly, better use numerical schemes such as Euler or Runge Kutta or Crank Nicholson, if you want only draw the curves of deformations . i hope it helps

Comment: Have you considered the substitution $y=\cosh t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
c\sqrt{1+{y^{'}}^2} -\rho g y +\lambda = 0 
$$

$$
1+{y^{'}}^2 = (\frac{-\lambda + \rho g y}{c})^2
$$
$$
{y^{'}}^2 = (\frac{(-\lambda + \rho g y)^2-c^2}{c^2})
$$
$$
\frac{{y^{'}}}{\sqrt{(-\lambda + \rho g y)^2-c^2}} = \frac{1}{c}
$$

$$
\frac{{{\frac{(-\lambda+ \rho g y)}{c}}^{'}}}{\sqrt{(\frac{-\lambda + \rho g y}{c})^2-1}} = \frac{\rho g}{c}
$$

$$
\left[\mathrm{argch}(\frac{-\lambda+\rho g y(u)}{c}) \right ]_{u=0}^{u=s} =  \int_{u=0}^{u=s}\frac{\rho g}{c} du
$$

and you try with the other when $y^{'} \le 0 $ adn you choose the physic one, pay attention in this case i choose $c \ge 0$